# piping data from tshark to java program

Tags: java, sql, tshark

i use tshark to capture TCP traffic and i want to creat java application that receive packets from tshark and extract some fields and then put these fields directly in SQL data base

in tshark i use this command

```
    C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -r 111.pcapng -T fields -e frame.number -e ip.
src -e tcp.window_size_value -e frame.time -e data.text -e tcp.analysis.duplicat
e_ack -e tcp.analysis.out_of_order -e tcp.analysis.retransmission -e tcp.analysi
s.fast_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.spurious_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.ze
ro_window -e tcp.stream -E header=y -E separator=, -l | java JavaApplication5
```

it works and start piping data to JavaApplication5 but nothin appear to me

here the code i use in java

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.*;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


/**
 *
 * @author sheda
 */
public class JavaApplication5 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String s;
        while ((s=in.readLine())!=null&&s.length()!=0) {            
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        } catch (LinkageError e) {
        }



    }

}
```

i use netbeans when i run it gives me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

why?

another idea i want to read from STDIN ans STDOUT of tshark directly and save what i read in string for future processing (compare string with predefined string format and extract info then forward it directly to SQL database )

any help here ?

thank you very much

Comment: Could you please include the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: i tried to add printstacktrace but it gave my this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaapplication8/JavaApplication8
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

Comment: You say you get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, but how do you know that? If it printed that exception on the console, then there should been an accompanying stack trace.

Comment: please read the answer i added @aioobe